# C# Hackerrank code produces correct results on Data Types challenge in 30 days of code but says I'm wrong

Tags: c#, types

Recently I have tried to solve Day 1 Data types lesson for the 30 days of Code challenge in hackerrank and I've run into a strange road block.The compiler keeps saying that my output is the wrong answer, but I print out the exact same integer double and string. **the only thing that's different is that I don't have a decimal point on my double,which doesn't make sense because The only thing I've done is read from the input,convert the input from a string to a double and then add the two doubles together**

Can you guys help? This is my C# code by the way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;



class Solution {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        string s = "HackerRank ";

     //this is the start of my code,the top part is preset by hackerrank
int a=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
string l = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(a+i);
Console.WriteLine(d+x);
Console.WriteLine(s+l);

Console.ReadLine();

}
}
```

here is there input they want me to use that I am using:

```
12
4.0
is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

Here is my output :

```
16
8
HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

And The output they want:

```
16
8.0
HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

**as you can see my ".0" is missing for my double, any help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.ToString()` with an overload to format your result:

```
Console.WriteLine((d+x).ToString("#.0"));
```

the `0` represents a default placeholder, if there is no decimal point it will add `0`. else it will show the actual value.

To answer your comments:

`#` represents any number preceding the `.`

Why does it strip the `.0` in your case: according to MSDN, `Console.WriteLine(double)` represents the output as a `string` using the default `ToString("G")` overload:

> The text representation of value is produced by calling the
>   Double.ToString method. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/219hw6yx(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> The general ("G") format specifier converts a number to the more
>   compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on the
>   type of the number and whether a precision specifier is present. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString)

According to the documentation above, if you were to change your data type to `decimal` instead of `double` the `.0` should be preserved.

Comment: so the 0 represents a default placeholder, then what does the "#" do?

Comment: Also thanks, It worked, but why did my  decimal point go away? I don't want to mark this question as answered, because I really need to know this and because i don't think  i should make a separate post about it.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for this, by the way, what is that "#.0" feature called? is it a special type of string formatting and/or placeholder? and is it exclusive to the .ToString() method?

Comment: It's part of the `ToString()` method, you can find all the options via MSDN

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F1}",d+x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add 0.0 to make it double value.